# Uncaught Error: Relay transform error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, graphql, relay

We are facing a problem with Relay/GraphQL/React in production. When testing in master everything works fine, however in production we get the following error in the console which causes everything related to Relay/GraphQL/React not to be working at all:

``` Uncaught Error: Relay transform error ``Map is not defined`` in file '/var/app/ondeck/app/react/relay/routes/xxx-route.jsx'. Try updating your GraphQL schema if an argument/field/type was recently added. ```

We believe is something related to the build of the application when it's getting deployed, however we have no idea where to start looking at.

This is my `package.json` in case it helps:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "eslint": "^2.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autobind-decorator": "^1.3.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "graphiql": "^0.7.2",
    "graphql": "^0.6.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.3.3",
    "postal": "^2.0.4",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-linkify": "^0.1.1",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.6",
    "react-relay": "^0.9.0",
    "react-star-rating-component": "^1.0.0",
    "react-stars": "^2.1.0",
    "react-webpack-rails": "^0.4.1",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack/production.config.js",
    "start": "webpack -w --config webpack/dev.config.js",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx app/react/**"
  },
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you come to a solution?

Comment: Hello @aleks, I forgot to post the solution here. We solved it by updating the node.js versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I needed to update Node.js to the latest version in order for everything to work again. Thanks.